# PHP How do I shift subset of array values to do something like asort?

Tags: php, sorting, arrays

First off I am new to this site and it is a big help, so thanks in advance for the input.

I am trying to shift a subset of array values after comparing them, like asort.

Here is what I have:

```
$array[name] = "name";
$array[date] = "date";
$array[item1] = 7;
$array[item2] = 16;
$array[item3] = 3;
$array[item4] = 16;
$array[item5] = 2;
$array[item6] = 10;
$array[author] = "author";
$array[location] = "location';
```

I would like to sort the itemsN values by sorting the values so the values of "16" are at end of the subset, and the values other than "16" are at the beginning of the subset.

So after the sort I want to end up with:

```
$array[name] = "name";
$array[date] = "date";
$array[item1] = 7;
$array[item2] = 3;
$array[item3] = 2;
$array[item4] = 10;
$array[item5] = 16;
$array[item6] = 16;
$array[author] = "author";
$array[location] = "location';
```

Comment: Could $array->item just be an array ? This way you could use the native function of PHP to sort.

Comment: Looks more like object properties than an array

Comment: Yes, it is an array.  I edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this reference

http://www.php.happycodings.com/code_snippets/code9.html

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to "sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association"?

```
arsort($array)
```

Or if you don't care about maintaing key/value association:

```
rsort($array)
```

Comment: I see. I have to admit that calling his object "array" and wanting to sort its members got me confused here.

Comment: Sorry it is an array.  Edited the question to reflect that.  I want to shift the subset of values, not sort the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

The [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) has an `asort()` method:

```
$array->asort();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' - ' . $value . "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1 - 2
2 - 2 
3 - 1
4 - 1
5 - 1
```

Comment: yeah, but it will sort the keys as well